# Results showed up in console but cant update the states in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("user.uid:", user.uid);
  const getUserData = async () => {
    const userRef = doc(collection(db, "users"), user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
    const userData = docSnap.data();
    console.log("userData:", userData);

    setName(userData.name || "");
    setPhone(userData.phone || "");
    setCfHandle(userData.cf_handle || "");
    setVjudgeHandle(userData.vjudge_handle || "");

    setLoading(false);
  };
  getUserData(); 
}, [user.uid]);
```

Here userData is shown in the console, but cant be shown in the Jsx by updating the states.

Comment: Can you provide component's complete source code ? are there any errors in devtools ?